# Should i put all my angular components in separate module for safer authentication?

Tags: angular, authentication, module

Is it better to create a new module containing all angular components that will be lazy-loaded after the user is authenticated (for security purposes) or it does not make any difference?

I work on a simple authorized based web page and i'm trying to made it a little bit safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for Lazy Loading of Angular Modules is generally to make the initial bundle load size smaller, This enables for faster loading of Angular Apps and better modularization.

But yeah, you can also consider security as a part of it. It's just that after you implement lazy loading, you should consider implementing [**`CanLoad`**](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) Guard.

Answer (score 1):

As per Angular Docs guideline, you can move component to separate module and lazy load on user demand. This is improve the app launch time and user time to interactivity. Lazy loaded modules can be accessed using Router.